# How to get JSON Structure inside array elements in Ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Hi I am a beginner in iOS and in my project I am working with JSON services.

Please see below JSON structure.

I want to get all "`languages`" inside elements but I do not understand how to get those fields.

Please help me.

### JSON STUCTURE:-

```
- loans: [
             - {
        id: 983381,
        name: "America",
        description:      {
        languages:      [
    name:   "English"
        ]
        },

    },

     - {
         id: 983382,
        name: "Jarmani",
        description:      {
        languages:      [
    name:   "Jarman"
        ]
        },

    },

 - {
         id: 983383,
        name: "Rasya",
        description:      {
        languages:      [
    name:   "Rasya"
        ]
        },

    },
]
```

### my code:-

```
 NSMutableArray * array1 = [mainDictyionary objectForKey:@"loans"];

    for (NSDictionary * obj in array1) {

       LangArray = [obj objectForKey:@"languages"];
    }

  NSLog(@"so finally  array values are  %@", LangArray);
```

Comment: can you tell me the datatype of LangArray

Comment: NSMUtableArray is datatype

Comment: answer posted. check it

Comment: present i am not near to  my mac system is your answer can print all "english","jarman","rasya" elements?

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Comment: sorry bro i am not near to my mac system that's why i can't check it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96369/discussion-between-krish-and-balaji-kondalrayal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are getting the value upto languages and not upto "english" or anyother. And also you are assigning the values to `LangArray`, so it will not add all the values it will add last value of the loop.

```
NSMutableArray * array1 = [mainDictyionary objectForKey:@"loans"];

NSMutableArray *LangArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary * obj in array1) {

       [LangArray addObject:[[obj objectForKey:@"languages"] objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }

  NSLog(@"so finally  array values are  %@", LangArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your language to your `LangArray` so it doesn't reassign in each loop.

```
NSMutableArray * array1 = [mainDictyionary objectForKey:@"loans"];

for (NSDictionary * obj in array1) {
   NSArray *language = [obj objectForKey:@"languages"];
   LangArray.addObject(language);
}
```